# adding the value of a column of database in c#

Tags: c#

I want to add the value of a database column in c# and want to save it in a variable . Please help me to ahead. Thanks in advance.

I thought the following: it is possible,

```
SqlCommand myCommand3 = new SqlCommand("select sum(credit_hour) from [student_reg] WHERE [std_id]= '" + id + "' ", myConnection);
```

Comment: you want to add the sum of credit_hour to variable?

Comment: That depends on what the column type is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

**Problem 1:** You don't need to enclose the Integer parameters within single quotes.

**Solution 1:**

```
SqlCommand myCommand3 = new SqlCommand("select sum(credit_hour) from 
                [student_reg] WHERE [std_id]= " + id, myConnection);
```

**Suggestion:** Your Query is open to *SQL Injection Attacks* i would suggest you to use *Parameterised Queries* to avoid them.

**Solution 2:** Using *Parameterised Queries*

```
SqlCommand myCommand3 = new SqlCommand("select sum(credit_hour) from 
                [student_reg] WHERE [std_id]= @id", myConnection);
myConnection.Open();
myCommand3.Parameters.AddWithVlaue("@id",id);
TextBox1.Text  = myCommand3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    SqlCommand myCommand3 = new SqlCommand("select sum(credit_hour) from [student_reg] WHERE [std_id]= @Id ", myConnection);
    myCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
    con.Open();
    int sum = (int) myCommand3.ExecuteScalar();
```